# Getting Error "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." while fetching data from XML tags using Java

Tags: java, xml

I am getting this ERROR MSG in Eclipse :

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-69564752\testng-customsuite.xml

[Fatal Error] TestExecutionDetails.xml:3:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

FAILED: LoginTest
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///C:/workspace/Pro1/bin/TestExecutionFiles/TestExecutionDetails.xml; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at Pro1.XMLData.getXMLtagValue(XMLData.java:29)
    at OR.Login.LoginTest(Login.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Here is my XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
    <Browser>Mozilla</Browser>
    <URL><![CDATA[https://google.mail.com]]></URL>
    <Uid>Testing</Uid>
    <Pwd>Test</Pwd>
```

Java Code to fetch data from XML Tags :

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XMLData {

        public static String getXMLtagValue (String tagName) throws Exception{
/*      FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream("test.xml");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
        StringBuilder str =  new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            str.append(line);
        }*/
        String tagValue = null;

        String myXMLfile = "C:\\workspace\\Pro1\\bin\\TestExecutionFiles\\TestExecutionDetails.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(myXMLfile);

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        String expression = "/"+tagName;

        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
               Node node = nodeList.item(i);
               System.out.println("node name: "+node.getNodeName());
               NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
               for(int j=0;j<childNodes.getLength();j++){
                   Node childNode = childNodes.item(j);
                   if(childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                       System.out.println(childNode.getNodeName()+"::"+childNode.getTextContent().trim());
                       System.out.println("--------attributes");
                       NamedNodeMap map = childNode.getAttributes();
                       for(int k=0; k<map.getLength();k++){
                           Node attnode = map.item(k);
                           tagValue = attnode.getNodeName()+attnode.getTextContent().trim();
                       }
                       //System.out.println("--------");
                   }

               }
                  //NamedNodeMap map = node.getAttributes();
        }
        return tagValue;
    }
}
```

TestNG Program :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import PageFactory.*;

public class Login {

    @Test
    public void LoginTest() throws Exception{

        String url = XMLData.getXMLtagValue("URL");
        String uid = XMLData.getXMLtagValue("Uid");
        String pwd = XMLData.getXMLtagValue("Pwd");

        WebDriver driver = Driver.callBrowser();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(url);
        LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        loginPage.username.sendKeys(uid);
        loginPage.pwd.sendKeys(pwd);
        loginPage.lbtn.click(); 
   }
}
```

CData is also not working.
And if there is any need for XSLT, please let me know how to work with it
Please HELP !!!!!

Comment: there is no root tag in you xml

Comment: root tag ? but y is it needed ? I am getting error at :3:2 which is URL tag actually ........ Please let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: every xml file needs a root tag to be well formed

Comment: If you don't have a root element, you don't have well-formed XML. If you don't have well-formed XML, you don't have XML. https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed Also, the error is at the `URL` element because the parser thinks that the first element (`Browser`) is the root element.

Comment: Got it ........ Thanks a lot ....... :)